# Element-wise comparison with NaNs as equal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

If I run the following code:

```
dft1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, np.nan, np.nan]})
dft2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, np.nan]})
dft1.a==dft2.a
```

The result is

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

How can I make the result to be

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

I.e., np.nan == np.nan evaluates to True.

I thought this is basic functionality and I must be asking a duplicate question, but I spent a lot of time search in SO or in Google and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 13):

Can't think of a function that already does this for you (weird) so you can just do it yourself:

```
dft1.eq(dft2) | (dft1.isna() & dft2.isna())

       a
0   True
1  False
2   True
```

Note the presence of the parentheses. Precedence is a thing to watch out for when working with overloaded bitwise operators in pandas.

Another option is to use `np.nan_to_num`, if you are certain the index and columns of both DataFrames are identical so this result is valid:

```
np.nan_to_num(dft1) == np.nan_to_num(dft2)

array([[ True],
       [False],
       [ True]])
```

`np.nan_to_num` fills NaNs with some filler value (0 for numeric, 'nan' for string arrays).

Comment: Thanks. I like the first option better. I will select your answer in a few days if nothing better comes up.

Comment: I'm guessing that this would equate `None` and `np.nan`

Comment: I'm also going to assume these are always floats and so there won't be any `None`

Answer (score 9):

Using [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with `equal_nan=True`:

```
np.isclose(dft1, dft2, equal_nan=True, rtol=0, atol=0)
```

```
array([[ True],
   [False],
   [ True]])
```

It's important to set both `atol` and `rtol` to zero to avoid equality assertions on similar values.

Comment: Cool! I vaguely recall a function with an `equal_nan` argument but not off the top of my head.

Comment: What if you set the tolerances here to 0?

Comment: You'd probably have to set the tols to 0, though, right?  .. aargh, beaten

Answer (score 4):

Since np.nan is not equal to np.nan

```
np.nan==np.nan
Out[609]: False



dft1.a.fillna('NaN')==dft2.a.fillna('NaN')
Out[610]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Interesting, you can probably also convert to string and repeat. ++

Comment: Thanks Wen. I have seen my colleagues doing this, but it sometimes can be dangerous because the magic word (`'NaN'` in your case) may already exist in the series.

Comment: Perhaps instead do `dft1.astype(str).eq(dft2.astype(str))`

Answer (score 2):

`np.nan` is defined to not be equal to `np.nan`.

### Iterate

Check each pair to be equal **or** all `np.nan`

```
def naneq(t):
  return (t[0] == t[1]) or np.isnan(t).all()

[*map(naneq, zip(dft1.a, dft2.a))]

[True, False, True]
```

---

### `nunique`

Count the unique values.  Make sure to set argument `dropna=False`

```
pd.concat([dft1, dft2], axis=1).nunique(1, 0) == 1

0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```