# Check if a series exists in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to check if a series already exists as a row in the dataframe. The dataframe is as follows-

```
        Name   Age   University
0      Ankit   NaN          BHU
1  Aishwarya  21.0          JNU
2    Shaurya  22.0           DU
```

I have tried-

```
(df == ser).all(1).any()
```

It works fine when the dataframe and series do not have null values. For example, if the series is `['Aishwarya', 21.0, 'JNU']`, the output is **True**, which is correct. However, if the series is `['Ankit', np.nan, 'BHU']`, the output is **False**, even if the series exists in the dataframe.

Minimum, reproducible example for my problem-

```py
details = {'Name':['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya'], 'Age':[np.nan, 21, 22], 'University':['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU']}
df = pd.DataFrame(details, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'University']) 

ser1 = pd.Series(['Ankit', np.nan, 'BHU'], index = ['Name', 'Age', 'University'])
ser2 = pd.Series(['Aishwarya', 21.0, 'JNU'], index = ['Name', 'Age', 'University'])

print((ser1 == df).all(1).any())
print((ser2 == df).all(1).any())
```

Actual Output-

```
False
True
```

Expected Output-

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition `np.nan == np.nan` is False

Try using `df.isin()` instead:

```
df.isin([*ser1]).all(1).any()
True
```

Comment: This returns **False**.

Comment: Hi @Shradha, changed it. I was originally testing with lists instead of series. Turning the series into a list already works out

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103594/element-wise-comparison-with-nans-as-equal/52103653#comment91158337_52103654) as well.

```py
print(ser1.astype(str).eq(df.astype(str)).all(1).any())  # True
print(ser2.astype(str).eq(df.astype(str)).all(1).any())  # True
```